# inserting multiple photos into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code, it has connection with database included:

```
session_start();

require 'config2.php';
require_once 'user.class.php';

$target = "uploads/"; 
$target1 = "uploads/"; 
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']); 
$target1 = $target1 . basename( $_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name']); 

//This gets all the other information from the form 
$login = $_SESSION['login'];    
$name=$_POST['name']; 
$name1 =$_POST['name1'];
$pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']); 
$pic1=($_FILES['photo1']['name1']); 

$id=$_SESSION['id'];

// Connects to your Database 
print_r($_POST);
print_r($_FILES);
print_r($_SESSION);
print_r($_GET);

//$op = mysql_query("select id from users where id = '$id' ");
//Writes the information to the database 
mysql_query("INSERT INTO users (name, photo, name1, photo1) VALUES ('$name', '$photo', '$name1', '$photo1') where login = '$login'") ; 

// mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name='$name', photo = '$pic', name1 = '$name1', photo1 = '$pic1' WHERE  login = '$login' ");
//Writes the photo to the server 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] ,$target) )
{ 
  //Tells you if its all ok 
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name'] ). " has been uploaded,        and your information has been added to the directory"; 
  echo "<a href = 'profile.php?id=$id'>back</a>"; 
} 

if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name'] ,$target1) )
{ 
  //Tells you if its all ok 
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name1'] ). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory"; 
  echo "<a href = 'profile.php?id=$id'>back</a>"; 
} 
else { 
  //Gives and error if its not 
  echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file."; 
}
```

This code works only for one image (uploads one image name into database field -photo), and only if I change insert to update. How to make it work with multiple images and with insert command ?

Comment: Mysql_* functions are deprecated.  You should look into mysqli or PDO, with prepared statements.  This is open to sql injection as is.

Comment: upload images as an array and insert those using a foreach loop?

Comment: Do you upload the pictures to MySQL? If yes, I would recommend uploading the link location instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at your indices and names of variables. You use `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name1']` and `$_FILES['photo1']['tmp_name']`. Are you sure that this is correct? POST data is in `$_POST` array, files information is in `$_FILES`. Names of uploaded files is in `$_FILES['photo1']['name']`. You will never have `$_FILES['uploadedfile']['name1']` set.

Also, what table structure do you have? Have you two name fields and two filepath fields?

Your query is incorrect. If you want to update table row, use `UPDATE ... WHERE ...` query. If you want to add new one, use `INSERT` without `WHERE`. You have commented correct one.

Also, use PDO and prepared statements, really. Your code allows SQL injections.

Comment: thanks, now it works, seems that I was too tired to see easy solution. Have you got any good tutorial about PDO? Is this a kind of library which i add to website ?

Comment: @mac PDO is built-in PHP module. [http://php.net/pdo](http://php.net/pdo). Official reference is good enough. Look at comments there to find examples. Always use bound params for data that user inputs. (No need to escape this data because params are passed separately.) In other words, you write statement template, bind params and execute statement.

Answer (score 0):

Enter a comma-separated list of rows.

```
INSERT INTO users (name, photo, name1, photo1) 
VALUES 
('$name', '$photo', '$name1', '$photo1'),
('$name', '$photo3', '$name2', '$photo4'),
('$name', '$photo5', '$name3', '$photo6');
```